# Url parsing and simplification in PHP

Tags: php, url, parsing

I'm parsing the links found on webpages, and I'm looking for a way to convert URLs like this:

```
http://www.site.com/./eng/.././disclaimer/index.htm
```

to the equivalent and more correct

```
http://www.site.com/disclaimer/index.htm
```

mainly for avoiding duplicates.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this

```
function simplify($path) {
   $r = array();
   foreach(explode('/', $path) as $p) {
      if($p == '..')
        array_pop($r);
      else if($p != '.' && strlen($p))
        $r[] = $p;
   }
   $r = implode('/', $r);
   if($path[0] == '/') $r = "/$r";
   return $r;
}
```

and this is how you use it

```
$u = parse_url($dirtyUrl);
$u['path'] = simplify($u['path']);
$clean_url = "{$u['scheme']}://{$u['host']}{$u['path']}";
```

Comment: Works!
Had to read your snippet ten times before understanding how it works :)
Thank you so much.

Comment: Why the "servicing" code is not wrapped into the function itself? :-) I would imagine function, which takes as a parameter dirtyUrl and returns cleanUrl. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what makes you think those two URL:s are equivalent?

If you can answer this question in a detailed fashion, use a regexp or parser to adhere to the rules which you know indicates that the pages are equivalent.

Comment: Those two URLs are equivalent because they lead to the same address.
If you type the "dirty" one on the address bar, the browser automatically simplifies it.